# Perl script compilation into .exe error

Tags: perl, komodo

I am trying to create a .exe in perl. It works fine until I try to compile it into an exe. I am using Komodo IDE 5. I have posted my script and the error below. I have added the modules, LWP::UserAgent, NET, and Google::Voice and it still doesnt work. I use perlapp to create the .exe

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Google::Voice;
use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days);
use Net::Twitter;

#Set Days
    my @today = (localtime)[5,4,3];
    $today[0] += 1900;
    $today[1]++;
    my @RT = (2012, 7, 7);
    my $days = Delta_Days(@today, @RT);

#Get Quotes and Phone Numbers
    open FILE, "c:/Countdown/countdownNumbers.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; 
    my $numbers = join("", <FILE>); 
    close FILE;
    open FILETWO, "c:/Countdown/Quotes.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; 
    my $quotes = join("", <FILETWO>); 
    close FILETWO;

#Create Arrays and Lengths
    my @numbersArray = split(/[\n\r\l]+/, $numbers);
    my @quotesArray = split(/[\n\r\l]+/, $quotes);
    my $length = @numbersArray;
    my $QuotesLength = @quotesArray;

#Send Text Message
    for(my $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        my $g = Google::Voice->new->login('secret', 'secret'); 
        $g->send_sms($numbersArray[$i] => "      Countdown\nDays Left: " . $days . "\n Quote:\n" . $quotesArray[0]);
    }


#Send Twitter Message
    my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
        traits   => [qw/OAuth API::REST/],
        consumer_key        => 'secret',
        consumer_secret     => 'secret',
        access_token        => 'secret',
        access_token_secret => 'secret'
    );
    my $result = $nt->update($days .' Days left!');
    $result = $nt->update('Quote: ' . $quotesArray[0]);

#Rewrite the file and close it
    open FILETWO, ">c:/Countdown/Quotes.txt";
    for(my $i = 1; $i < $QuotesLength; $i++){
        print FILETWO $quotesArray[$i] . "\n";
    }
    close FILETWO;
```

errors

```
Algorithm\Diff\XS.pm:
    error: Can't locate Algorithm\Diff\XS.pm
    refby: C:\Perl\site\lib\Array\Diff.pm line 7
Date\Calc\XS.pm:
    error: Can't locate Date\Calc\XS.pm
    refby: C:\Perl\lib\Date\Calc.pm line 26
I18N\Langinfo.pm:
    error: Can't locate I18N\Langinfo.pm
    refby: C:\Perl\lib\Encode\Locale.pm line 51
JSON\PP58.pm:
    error: Can't locate JSON\PP58.pm
    refby: C:\Perl\lib\JSON\PP.pm
Net.pm:
    error: Can't locate Net.pm
    refby: perlapp --add Net::

Can't locate Mojo/EventEmitter.pm in @INC (@INC contains:) at /<C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Countdown\RT.exe>Mojo/Base.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /<C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Countdown\RT.exe>Mojo/UserAgent.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /<C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\RTCountdown\RT.exe>Google/Voice.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at RT.pl line 4.
```

Comment: Nice to get a vote down and no reason why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling perl script into exe file is not so straight-forward, I'm afraid. ) Check [this discussion at Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=930537) for details.

From what you've quoted it seems that you might start  fixing that with installing additional modules: Algorithm::Diff::XS, Date::Calc::XS, etc.

Comment: I have added the modules it wants and it gives the same errors Can't locate Mojo/EventEmitter.pm in @INC (@INC contains:) at /<C:\RTCountdown\RT.exe>Mojo/Base.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /<C:\RTCountdown\RT.exe>Mojo/UserAgent.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /<C:\RTCountdown\RT.exe>Google/Voice.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at RTX.pl line 4.

Comment: shinjuou, so `--add Mojo::EventEmitter`

Answer (score 2):

If you use latest version of perlapp, send this error to ActiveState support.

Temporarily you can use PAR::Packer instead of perlapp. Install PAR::Packer with cpan shell (ppm may not work). Then run

```
pp -c t1.pl
```

It will create a.out. If it would not work, install Module::ScanDeps from svn: http://svn.openfoundry.org/par/Module-ScanDeps/trunk/ - I fixed a couple of possible problems for your program.

I never used perlapp, but it may have command line switches to provide a list of modules to include.

Comment: I have never used PAR::Packer and it is asking me to setup GCC environment which I dont know what that is and I cant type in it anyways. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: In newer versions it will be install automatically, in older - AFAIR it can be installed with `ppm install gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded `Langinfo.pm` from http://search.cpan.org/src/RJBS/perl-5.16.1/ext/I18N-Langinfo/Langinfo.pm to `C:\Perl\lib\I18N` and it works.

- Komodo IDE, version 6.1.3
- Perl Dev Kit Pro v9.1.1.
- ActivePerl-5.14.2.1402-MSWin32-x86-295342